# Для детей младшего школьного возраста(.) Нужна ли точка?

Tags: пунктуация, редактура

После аннотации в книге, с отрывом от неё даётся рекомендация: *Для детей младшего школьного возраста.*

Надо ли после этого ставить точку? Это вроде как подпись, после которой точки не ставятся. Где можно про это (про точки после подписей, издательских помет) можно почитать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта фраза (об адресности книги) обычно замыкает аннотации, предисловия. Она, хотя и даётся с красной строки, функционально вписывается в эти краткие ознакомительные тексты.

Рассматривать такую рекомендацию как некую подпись нет причин. Точка необходима.

Comment: К подписи (т. е. отд. строке или неполным— флажком — строкам) можно отнести указание на авторство, а также сведения об иллюстрации.